# Running Overloaded methods in java in sequence?

Tags: java, overloading

Hello I'm looking to do something like this

public void X (int A, double B)
{}

public void X (double Y, char Z)

X++

with just one value of x the array looks like this

public final Array[] array1 = {

new X (double,char)

// execute, wait

new X (int,double)

//once previous segment is finished execute,wait

//repeat until all are complete. segement will return null, ending the array and allowing for next operations to run.
ive tried to use both x versions but i was given a nullpointer exception. im trying to figure out where the problem is.

i want them to run in a sequence where both of them will act as the same operation with different actions preformed in each. When applied they each should take several seconds to complete. so my goal is to have one version of x run, wait for completion then run another version of x. 
i know that if i have one version of x they run consecutively. but when i run 2 versions of x Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Call them sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

```
>     public void X(int a, int b){
      //code
>     }

>     public void X(double a, double b){
      //code
>     }
```

Call these function from the method you want passing them with correct arguments

Answer (score 0):

Just return this in the function. If you think this.X(10,10).X(10.0,10) is calling sequentially

## Code

```
public class Test {

    public Test  X(int a, int b) {
       System.out.println("X1");
       return this;
    }
    public Test  X(double a, int b) {
       System.out.println("X2");
       return this;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.X(10,10).X(10.0,10);
    }

}
```

If you compile and run

## Output

```
X1
X2
```

Comment: Each function is used for an application that takes time to complete. For example each method has one value that makes it 'wait'. I need one to complete before the next begins. Does your example allow this?

Comment: @tkgn15 It's not clear that you know how Java works; if you call methods sequentially, they run sequentially. If the methods you *call* do something with threads and you need the results of those separate processes sequentially, then you'd need to *tell* us that.